# Issue with Certbot: "no valid A records found" during certificate renewal

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, gunicorn, linode

I'm encountering an issue with Certbot while trying to renew SSL certificates for my domain using the --nginx option. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx -d your_domain.com -d www.your_domain.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for your_domain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. your_domain.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: no valid A records found for your_domain.com; no valid AAAA records found for your_domain.com

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: your_domain.com
   Type:   None
   Detail: no valid A records found for your_domain.com; no valid
   AAAA records found for your_domain.com
$
```

I am not sure exactly what to look for to fix this error. I am using Lindo Akamai and the A/AAAA Record
is showing the correct IP address also the website is working fine without as Http. I am using Nginx and Gunicorn for a Django Project.

My question how to fix the error everytime I run `sudo certbot --nginx -d your_domain.com -d www.your_domain.com`

Comment: How long ago did you add the records, have they maybe not propagated yet?  Can you do normal DNS lookup of the failing domain on the command line on the server where you're running certbot?  Eg `dig your_domain.com`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Here,
**sudo certbot --nginx -d your_domain.com -d www.your_domain.com**
you are adding **your_domain.com** and **www.your_domain.com** (two entries, one with www. and one without www.)

The error is saying that there is no A record for your_domain.com (without **www.**)
So just add new A record without **www.** It worked for me (Using google domain service)
EDIT: If your DNS/hosting provider does not support entires without **www.** you  can add an entry with just '**@**' (which usually means the root of the domain). It worked for me on justhost.com

Comment: Tip: no need to create A records for all prefixes (e.g. `www.example.com` in addition to `example.com`). Just make sure base `example.com` has A record and point `www.example.com` via CNAME record to `example.com`.